# Как в c++ вывести массив строк

Tags: c++

ошибка Segmentation fault

Пишу

```
const char *mas[] = { "asdfsg",
                      "1231252",
                      "kjl,hjl,",
                      "0898-0",
                      "uyiiyu",
                      "----------" };

for ( int a = 0; '\0' !=  mas[a]; a++ )
{
    cout << mas[a]  << endl;
};
```

На выходе получаю:

> asdfsg 1231252 kjl,hjl, 0898-0 uyiiyu
> Segmentation fault

Если я правильно понимаю, указатель выходит за границу массива. Как это можно исправить Если я точно указываю кол-во строк, программа работает исправно, но как обойтись без подсчёта строк?

Comment: @Николай135326 а почему вы считаете, что ваш массив должен заканчиваться элементом '\0'? Если вам нужна итерация по элементам без учета индексов, то для этого имеет смысл исмользовать контейнеры

Comment: пользуюсь c++
а как это сделать (если возможно, то не указывать количество строк - чтобы можно было добавить 1-2 строки и не переписывать параметры?)

Comment: >а как это сделать

читайте внимательнее написанное выше: 

>Если вам нужна итерация по элементам без учета индексов, то для этого имеет смысл исмользовать контейнеры

Comment: У вас есть два выхода. Простой, нормальный: откажитесь от нативных массивов и строк, перейдите на стандартные контейнеры и `std::string`, они для новичков попроще будут. Сложный: прочитайте книжку по C и разберитесь с тем, что такое массив и C-style-строка.

Я бы советовал начать с первого, и постепенно переходить ко второму.

Comment: Про пустую строку в качестве ограничителя размера массива Вам уже рассказал @insolor.

Еще пара способов. Первый -- это граница в виде пустого *указателя*, я бы сказал, в стиле параметров командной строки (вспомните `main(int ac, char *av[]) {` ... (как раз для Вашего кода)):

    char *mas[] = {"s1", "s2", "s3", 0}; // запись тривиальна

Второй -- вычислить размер массива:

    int n = sizeof(mas) / sizeof(mas[0]);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         puts(mas[i]);

Понятно, что второй способ применим только в области видимости определения массива (т.е. с параметром не пойдет).

Answer (score 4):

Выход из цикла сделан так, как будто вы проходите по строке, а у вас - массив строк. Вам нужно либо явно задать длину массива ( `for(a=0; a<6; a++)` ), либо добавить в массив завершающий элемент, например пустую строку, но и в этом случае проверка на конец массива будет выглядеть по-другому:

```
const char *mas[] = {
   "asdfsg", "1231252", "kjl,hjl,", "0898-0", "uyiiyu", "----------",
   "" };

for ( int a = 0; mas[a][0]!='\0'; a++ ) {
    cout << mas[a] << endl;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Цикл уходит в бесконечность. Вы проверяете первый символ строки mas[a] на равенство нуль-терминатору, что является в корне неверным подходом.
Если используете с++ - у Вас есть возможность использования stl vector. Ваш код написан в С-стиле, а значит: или определяйте размер, или пользуйтесь средствамм string+vector.